# I am trying to batch some lists according to each list's weight in Python

Tags: python, list

The idea is to group the products in list `o` while making sure that upon grouping them they do not exceed the cap given by looking at the list called `w`. currently running this code gives me an "index out of range" but since I actively change the main list, is there like a way I can update it in? Is there another way? I would really appreciate all the help I can get

```
from pandas.core.common import flatten

w = [15.0, 5.0, 5.0,2,4]
o = [[3, [1, 2]], 4, 5,6,7]
M = [[5, 5, 5], [5], [5],[2],[6]]
cap = 15
LEN = len(o)

for i in range(1,LEN):
    if len(o) > 2:
        for j in range(1,LEN):
            if i != j and w[i] + w[j] <= cap:
                O1 = o[i]
                O2 = o[j]
                W1 = w[i]
                W2 = w[j]
                M1 = M[i]
                M2 = M[j]
                print("wow",i,j)
  
    
                TUP = [o[i],o[j]]
                o.remove(O1)
                o.remove(O2)
                o.append(TUP)
                
                
                WTEMP = w[i] + w[j]
                w.remove(W1)
                w.remove(W2)
                w.append(WTEMP)
                
                MTEMP = [M1,M2]
                MTEMP = list(flatten(MTEMP))
                M.remove(M1)
                M.remove(M2)
                M.append(MTEMP)
                print(w,o,M)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to iterate over `w` but you're doing it based on the size of `o` which is never guaranteed to be the same size. This is causing your issue.

You can add extra guards to the `if` condition to ensure that you're not going to overstep the bounds of `w`.

```
for i in range(1,LEN):
    if len(o) > 2:
        for j in range(1,LEN):
            if i != j and i < len(w) and j < len(w) and w[i] + w[j] <= cap:
                ...
```